# Facebook Error: An error occurred with app. Please try again later

Tags: php, facebook, oauth, facebook-oauth

My code which was working until yesterday, all of a sudden has started throwing errors. No clue what changed et all. It is also based on code from [Facebook Serve side authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/) Also I referred to others posts with the similar title but tried what they mention with not much luck.

Here is the code

```
<?php 

   $app_id = "my app id";
   $app_secret = "my app secret";
   $my_url = "http://apps.facebook.com/myappnamespace";
```

//Tried with https in my_url
//Also tried with the direct path to the app both with http and https and does not work as well.
       session_start();
       $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

```
   if(empty($code)) {
     $_SESSION['state'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)); //CSRF protection
     $dialog_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
       . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) . "&state="
       . $_SESSION['state'];

     echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
   }

   if($_REQUEST['state'] == $_SESSION['state']) {
     $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
       . "client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
       . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret . "&code=" . $code;

     $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
     $params = null;
     parse_str($response, $params);

     $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" 
       . $params['access_token'];

     $user = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));
     echo("Hello " . $user->name);
   }
   else {
     echo("The state does not match. You may be a victim of CSRF.");
   }

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be other ways to fix this but the php way usually never worked for me. I changed the approach to Javascript sdk way and things have been better.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you're using HTTP in the redirect URL, but you're trying to authenticate with HTTPS. Change the URL in `$my_url` to `https://` and see if it works.

Comment: This sends it outside the facebook canvas instead of loading in the canvas.